# API Manager JWT microservices JWTInterceptor giving Token has expired

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I wanted to setup API Manager generating JWT tokens. We setup IS as key manager. user will get authorized from IS, API Manager should generate JWT and send it to microservices. I setup a JWTSecurityInterceptor and CustomJWTClaimsInterceptor in the microservices. but when it got the JWT token from API manager, it has the exp setup as past time and always getting "Token has expired" error. PLease help me what am I doing wrong.

I followed this doc to setup the JWT generator in AM. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT

I am using AM 2.0.0 and IS 5.2.0.

Thanks
Ravi Ada

Comment: I tried to follow this link and change JWTExpiry setting but it still not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576348/wso2-api-manager-how-to-change-the-expiration-time-of-jwt

Comment: I even tried with a custom jwt generator and configured api manager to use the custom JWT generator, it is not working. I also followed the 2.0.0 documentation to set the ```JWTClaimCacheExpiry``` to 60 mins, that did not work.. And tried with enabling the ```EnableGatewayTokenCache``` and ```EnableKeyManagerTokenCache```. Seems like nothing is working for me. None of these changes are actually effecting how the JWT token is generated to send to backend microservice. Always getting the ```exp``` as the currenttimestamp and getting ```Token has expired``` message. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found that this issue is only when we configure IS as the key manager. If this is the case, actual JWT token is generated in AM or IS? How do we configure JWT expiration timestamp in IS?

Comment: if you are using IS as keymanager JWT settings will be in <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+the+API+Manager+1.8.0+or+1.7.0

Comment: if time is expired when jwt arrive at microservice due to network or any other delays, you will need to setup a time skew to in microservice